# Reference a node's color by using node name

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, tikz-styles, mindmaps

I am trying to use a node name to reference the node's color. I am not sure if this is even possible.

I have a Ti*k*Z `mindmap`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,backgrounds}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
\begin{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap, grow cyclic, every node/.style=concept, concept color=orange!40,
level 1/.append style={level distance=2cm,sibling angle=90},
level 2/.append style={level distance=1.7cm,sibling angle=45}]

\tikzset{every node/.append style={scale=0.6}}

\node{Root}
child [concept color=blue!30] { node (c1) {Child1}
}
child [concept color=yellow!60] { node (c2) {Child2}
};
\newcommand{\connCOnetoCTwo}{to[circle connection bar switch color=from (blue!30) to (yellow!60)]}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}

  \path (c1) \connCOnetoCTwo (c2);

\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\label{MindMap} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

My question is: Can I use the node names `c1` or `c2` and reference their colors
So something like (`c1.fill color`) when I use `\newcommand` to replace the `(blue!30)` and `(yellow!60)`.
So it will look like this pseudocode:

```
\newcommand{\connCOnetoCTwo}{to[circle connection bar switch color=from (c1.color) to (c2.color)]}
```

**Edited - code is now compliable

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This is a very interesting question! To make it even better, please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: One thing I have done is have a command which both names a node, assigns a colour to it and gives that colour another name which is tied to the node's name. So, e.g. if I tell it to make a node `bob`, it might assign `bob` blue, name the node `bob` and assign the colour name `bob colour` to blue. Then it is possible to access the node's colour later on the basis of its name, without knowing that `bob colour` is actually blue. That's not quite what you asked for but, depending on what you are trying to do, it might or might not be a possible solution.

Comment: @cfr Are you using \definecolor to do that?

Comment: @EliadCohen `\colorlet`

Answer (score 5):

This is what I got so far.

First I found, in `tikz.code.tex`, that Ti*k*Z stores your colors in `\tikz@fillcolor`, `\tikz@strokecolor`, and `\tikz@textcolor`. So I wrote a test.

[image]

```
\tikzset{
    every text node part/.add code={}{
        \xdef\thisnodefillcolor{\tikz@fillcolor}
        \xdef\thisnodedrawcolor{\tikz@strokecolor}
        \xdef\thisnodetextcolor{\tikz@textcolor}
    }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thick]
    \draw(0,0)node[fill=red,draw=green,text=blue]{Foo};
\end{tikzpicture} \\
fill: \thisnodefillcolor \\
draw: \thisnodedrawcolor \\
text: \thisnodetextcolor \\
```

But there is a limitation that if any of them is not assigned *explicitly*, I would get nothing. That is, both

```
    \draw(0,0)node[red]{Foo};
```

and

```
    \draw[red](0,0)node{Foo};
```

lead to empty `\thisnodexxx`'s. We will come back to this issue later.

---

Next, I found that colors assigned by `concept color` is stored in `\tikz@concept@color`. Since we want to refer to this color later, we create two aliases: `c1.conc` and `c2.conc`. In case one forgets to assign a color, `c1.conc` /`c2.conc` will be set to the *current color*.

[image]

```
\tikzset{
    every text node part/.add code={}{
        \globalcolorstrue
        \ifx\tikz@concept@color\pgfutil@empty
            \pgfutil@colorlet{\tikz@fig@name.conc}{.}
        \else
            \pgfutil@colorlet{\tikz@fig@name.conc}{\tikz@concept@color}
        \fi
    }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap,grow cyclic,every node/.style=concept,concept color=orange!40]
    \node{Root}
        child[concept color=blue!30]{node(c1){Child1}}
        child[concept color=yellow!60]{node(c2){Child2}};
    \newcommand\connCOnetoCTwo[2]{(#1)to[circle connection bar switch color=from (#1.conc) to (#2.conc)](#2)}
    \path\connCOnetoCTwo{c1}{c2};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Please notice that `c1.conc` is not an objective-oriented notion. It is a color named so. Also it is not guaranteed that `c1.conc` is always the name because `\tikz@fig@name` may contain prefix and suffix.

---

Combine these two methods I get:

[image]

```
\tikzset{
    every text node part/.add code={}{
        \globalcolorstrue
        \ifx\tikz@fillcolor\pgfutil@empty
            \pgfutil@colorlet{\tikz@fig@name.fill}{.}
        \else
            \pgfutil@colorlet{\tikz@fig@name.fill}{\tikz@fillcolor}
        \fi
        \ifx\tikz@strokecolor\pgfutil@empty
            \pgfutil@colorlet{\tikz@fig@name.draw}{.}
        \else
            \pgfutil@colorlet{\tikz@fig@name.draw}{\tikz@strokecolor}
        \fi
        \ifx\tikz@textcolor\pgfutil@empty
            \pgfutil@colorlet{\tikz@fig@name.text}{.}
        \else
            \pgfutil@colorlet{\tikz@fig@name.text}{\tikz@textcolor}
        \fi
    }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thick,scale=.6]
    \draw[violet](0,-3)node(c3){Foo};
    \draw(0,-4)node[fill=red,draw=green,text=blue](c4){Bar};
    \draw(0,-5)node[fill=c4.draw,draw=c4.text,text=c4.fill](c5){hakuna};
    \draw(0,-6)node[fill=c2.draw,draw=c3.text,text=c4.conc](c6){matata};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

See how I assign colors for `(c6)`? We could see that `c2.draw`, for some reason, is synced to `c2.conc`; `c3.text`, for another reason, is sync to `[violet]`; and `c4.conc`, by default, becomes black.

As for the explicitness issue, it is `xcolor`'s *current color* doing the magic. I did not test them so much so leave comments for any further problems.

Nevertheless, you may try to replace `every text node part/.add code` by `every node/.code` or something. It gives errors because Ti*k*Z executes `every`'s in its own order. In fact, `every node` is executed before those colors are processed. You can read `tikz.code.tex` to find out a better place to hack. And keep in mind that everything about `fig` is a node. (I guess)

Comment: Thank you for this very in-depth reply. I appreciate the time you put into this it adds important conditional assignment of the colors to the aliases and enhances @cfr 's answer